# Increasing the range of an extraordinary ability-granted Blindsight

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

My character is a Level 5 Rogue, who is blind, and for reasons has blindsight out to 40 feet as an extraordinary ability. This doesn't come from an item or feat.

Is there a way to increase the range of that blindsight?

Comment: thanks dopplegreener. my questionfu is a bit weak. its been a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, no. Blindsight is an *extremely* powerful ability (within its range), so there's no easy way to get it and no standard way to enhance it.

That said, there's a 3rd party race called the [Squole](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/alluria-publishing/squole) from Alluria Publishing that gains blindsight 40' racially.  They're basically humanoidish, player-character-viable oozes.  I mention this for two reasons.

First, part of their racial description appears to be relevant to you:

> Squoles offer an opportunity to add a character to the party who has very different strengths and weaknesses when it comes to senses. While blindsight has several distinct rewards (see in the dark, immune to blindness, etc), there are also several drawbacks. The first is that squoles are extremely nearsighted…a foe that is only 45 feet away is effectively invisible. This creates a certain balance, where the squole will have the advantage in some situations, and disadvantage in others.
>
> Consequentially, the squole may face more of a struggle in some games than in others. Scenarios with an overwhelming majority of long range opponents may be extremely challenging for a squole who won’t be able to see these adversaries. On the other hand, if opponents rely on invisibility or darkness, the squole will have the upper hand.

Secondly, they have a [racial feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/alluria-publishing/general-feats---3rd-party---alluria-publishing/honed-senses) that improves their blindsight.  You can talk to your GM about letting you take it (or something based on it) to improve yours.

> **Honed Senses**
>
> *You have honed your blindsight to be more acute.*
>
> Prerequisite: Squole, Wis 13
>
> Benefit: Your blindsight range gains an additional number of feet equal to 5 times your Wisdom bonus (if any). For example, if your Wisdom bonus is +3, your blindsight extends to 55 feet.